# Is there a way to edit this script to overwrite a csv on the server rather than download locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to use tabletoCSV.js to allow a client to edit their prices in an editable html table and export the changes to overwrite the existing csv file.

```
jQuery.fn.tableToCSV = function() {

var clean_text = function(text){
    text = text.replace(/"/g, '""');
    return '"'+text+'"';
};

$(this).each(function(){
        var table = $(this);
        var caption = $(this).find('caption').text();
        var title = [];
        var rows = [];

        $(this).find('tr').each(function(){
            var data = [];
            $(this).find('th').each(function(){
                var text = clean_text($(this).text());
                title.push(text);
                });
            $(this).find('td').each(function(){
                var text = clean_text($(this).text());
                data.push(text);
                });
            data = data.join(",");
            rows.push(data);
            });
        title = title.join(",");
        rows = rows.join("\n");

        var csv = title + rows;
        var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
        var download_link = document.createElement('a');
        download_link.href = uri;
        var ts = new Date().getTime();
        if(caption==""){
            download_link.download = ts+".csv";
        } else {
            download_link.download = caption+"-"+ts+".csv";
        }
        document.body.appendChild(download_link);
        download_link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(download_link);
});
```

};

As of right now, it simply downloads a generic csv file. Assume the name of the file is "menu.csv".

Comment: Not at all clear how you want this to work.

Comment: I want it to overwrite a file, rather than download a file.

Comment: you have to post the data to server to do that

Comment: Correct, this is what I am trying to do. Post the html table as a csv file to the server so that it overwrites the existing csv of the same name. Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Comment: jQuery `$.ajax` or shorthand method `$.post` http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: Thanks, I'll sift through and see what I can do.

Comment: there are lots of tutorials around on how to use ajax